# typescript says property push is not available for "Location[] | Thenable<Location[] | null | undefined>"

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

Inside a VSCode extension I tried the follwing:

```
enter code here
getTest(label: string): vscode.Location[] {
    let result: vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.Location[]> = [];
        vscode.workspace.findFiles('*.m').then((files) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                let path = files[i].fsPath;
                fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', (err, content: string) => {
                    result.push(new vscode.Location(vscode.Uri.file(path), new vscode.Position(1, 1)));
                });
            }
        });
    return result;      
}
```

But the Compiler says "object is possibly null or undefined", property push is not available at the result.push... line.
Any Ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Per the type, `result` is either `Location[]` or `Thenable<Location[] | null | undefined>` - if it's the latter, it indeed doesn't have a `push` method.

Comment: Therefore you probably want to type the variable like `result: vscode.Location[]` instead of `vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.Location[]>`